# Data validation in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried a script that is example of google script for data validation. I just copied - paste the script below, could you help please?

```
function validateMySpreadsheet() {
  // Set a rule for the cell B4 to be a number between 1 and 100.
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B4');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
     .requireNumberBetween(1, 100)
     .setAllowInvalid(false)
     .setHelpText('Number must be between 1 and 100.')
     .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
```

Comment: Did you try to run the script as a bound script (e.g. one "stuck" to a Google Sheet that you access through Tools > Script Editor), or did you make a blank, so-called "unbound" script in, say, Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are receiving the `Cannot read property 'getRange' of null` is because most likely you don't have an *active sheet* available - meaning the script you are using is not bound to any spreadsheet.

In order to fix this, I suggest you make the following changes to your code:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS_ID');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
var cell = sheet.getRange('B4');
```

I also suggest you take a look at the below links since they might be of help to you.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound);
- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid);
- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Class - getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).